# How to place UIView Over Cell Border

Tags: swift, layout, cell

Hi I want to place a UIView at top of cell but when I show this cell a border of cell is over a UIView. How can I resolve it?
This is my result
[screen of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2448.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

for all those who have had this problem here is the solution:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    draw(self.frame)
}

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.gray.set()
        let path =  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 20)
        path.lineWidth = 2
        path.stroke()
    }
```